Unable to make eslint playwright plugin to work using eslint.config.mjs
I am new to Typescript universe. In my Playwright Typescript project, I just have eslint.config.mjs file. This file got created when I install eslint using npm init @eslint/config@latest.
Then I just removed its contents and replaced it with the contents from:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-playwright
I don't have any eslintignore file too.
My eslint.config.mjs file look like this:

import playwright from 'eslint-plugin-playwright'

export default [
  {
    ...playwright.configs['flat/recommended'],
    files: ['test/**', 'src/**'],
  },
  {
    files: ['test/**', 'src/**'],
    rules: {
      // Customize Playwright rules
      // ...
    },
  },
]


With this, when I run the command, am getting this warning and nothing is happening:
npx eslint test/MyTest.spec.ts
Warning:

/Users/user/IdeaProjects/automation/test/MyTest.spec.ts
  0:0  warning  File ignored because of a matching ignore pattern. Use "--no-ignore" to disable file ignore settings or use "--no-warn-ignored" to suppress this warning

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)

My dependency in package.json file look like this:


    "@eslint/js": "^8.57.0",
    "@playwright/test": "^1.44.1",
    "@types/node": "^20.14.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.13.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.13.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-playwright": "^1.6.2",
    "globals": "^15.5.0",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5",
    "typescript-eslint": "^7.13.0"


